# I can't figure out why 100% width doesn't work with a background image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a webpage. I'm having a little difficulty 
with getting my background picture to show up. I had it up and running, but I decided I wanted to give it a responsive design, and I can't figure it out. This is my code for the image:

```
<style>
    body .title_img {
        background-image: url("SplashScreen.jpg");
        height: auto;
         width: 100%;
        background-position: center;
        z-index: -1;
    }
</style>

<div class="title_img">
    <!-- Background Splash Screen -->
</div>
```

If I give the height/width a definitive size (pixels) it shows up. I don't understand why 100% width with auto height wouldn't give me a picture that is 100% the size of the body (which I THINK i have made sure it was the 100% of the html document) and a height that is automatically proportional to the width. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT- Added the HTML code.

Comment: Can you show the html code as well?

Comment: Sorry I'm very new to this website and coding in HTML and CSS.

Comment: basically why it doesn't work: the height of the div is 0, because the div doesn't containing anything, it just have a background image, but the size of background image doesn't defining the height of the div

Comment: If you want to your code to work you can add "position: fixed; left: 0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0 " to the css, but I think it has way more better solution for this, this is just how you can have in this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Full-Page Background Images**

I think what you are trying to create, is a full-page background image for your website. Based off of reading the code you provided, I believe you want something that does the following:

- Fills entire page with image, no white space
- Scales image as needed
- Retains image proportions (aspect ratio)
- Image is centered on page
- Does not cause scrollbars
- As cross-browser compatible as possible
- Isn't some fancy shenanigans like Flash

If that is what you are trying to create, then I found a few lines of code that could help. Here is an example of how you could go about doing this with your image using `css`:

**CSS File (That's where the magic happens):**

```
html { 
  background: url("SplashScreen.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Just make sure your `html` file is setup correctly to use the `css` file, and it should create a cool background image you can use for your websites.

You can read more into this [here](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) and learn more about what makes this work.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I didn't even think of using the whole html (whats the word for it, element?) for the background. Thank you sir, I will definitely read into your link.

Comment: The reason for why the <html> element was used instead of <body> element is because of something we like to call the "CSS Box Model" , which I believe is what was giving you trouble. It's not MANDITORY you use only css when doing a project like this, but as you can see from the code, it's much more simple to use. I'm sure you have probably heard of the box model before, but if not, here is a link to get you started: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp. The lesson before the box model is height / width, which I would take a look at as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `height: 100%` in `body` and `html` in your css:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

And then put `background-size: cover` in `body .title_img`:

```
body .title_img {
    background-image: url("SplashScreen.jpg");
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

See reference [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_full_page).

Comment: This has caused the photo to appear and it scales correctly when resizing the window, but it has moved down the <div> that was placed over it. Is it possible for the image be in the fixed position AND center while being adjustable to window size?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
background-size: cover
```

or

```
background-size:100% 100%.
```

with

```
background-repeat: no-repeat
```

That will set it to 100% of its container.